# Python3 - sanitizing user input passed to shell as parameter

Tags: python-3.x, security, sanitization

What is the recommended method of sanitizing user_input_parameter passed to the shell like

```
subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'rm -rf', user_input_parameter])
```

The command should accept all parameters but malicious activies like breaking out of the command should be mitigated.

Answer (score 4):

Python's implementation of `subprocess` protects against shell injection, [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) says so:

> #### 17.5.2. Security Considerations
>
> Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never
>   implicitly call a system shell. This means that all characters,
>   including shell metacharacters, can safely be passed to child
>   processes. If the shell is invoked explicitly, via `shell=True`, it is
>   the application’s responsibility to ensure that all whitespace and
>   metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid [shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_injection#Shell_injection)
>   vulnerabilities.
>
> When using `shell=True`, the [shlex.quote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) function can be used to
>   properly escape whitespace and shell metacharacters in strings that
>   are going to be used to construct shell commands.

This will however NOT protect against a user passing a malicious input - in your case for example deleting something that was not intended to be deleted. I would not pass user input to the command directly like that - you should verify if whatever you want to be deleted is being deleted and not something completely different. That is however part of application's logic already - regarding shell injection (*breaking out of the command*) - that should be fine with `subprocess`.

I made this little example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

user_input_parameter = '/; id'
subprocess.Popen(['ls', user_input_parameter])
```

Which outputs this when executed:

```
$ python3 asdf.py
ls: /; id: No such file or directory
$
```

To demonstrate `subprocess` passes the input as an argument to the parameter.

All of this is true *only* if `shell=False` (default as of writing this answer) for `subprocess` methods, otherwise you basically enable shell (bash, etc.) execution and allow for injection to happen if inputs are not properly sanitized.

---

Btw, you need to pass each parameter separately, so you would need to run it like this (but please don't do that):

```
subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'rm', '-rf', user_input_parameter])
```